# SAP Credit note - Item data texts (language issue)

Tags: abap, bapi

In credit note, in item data section, there is a tab with Texts. [image: item data]

Those credit notes are created by report/application where you upload file, then hit simulation and release mode button. Those 2 buttons contains a lot of code, but what those buttons do, they fill required tables and create credit note. I went through whole code and found all tables that contains "Notiz".
[image: Notiz in table]
I deleted those rows, but in the end, when credit note is created, there are still 2 texts with Notiz in item data.

Have you experienced something similar ? Or what are your suggestions ?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, these texts may be passed through file, output determination, idoc, service or whatever, and you deleted them in debugger from a temporary table that doesn't matter at all.

Comment: `Those 2 buttons contains a lot of code` either try to understand what those code does or call for an ABAPer

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found where is the problem.
In table LT_BAPISDTEXT, in column ITM_NUMBER value is missing.
[image: value missing]

I need to insert correct value from another table (LT_TEXT_LINES) 
[image: correct value]

[image]

[image]